# Handling NULL value in JSON response : Python Flask

Tags: python, flask

I have a JSON response that's having NULL for most of the key-value pairs within the JSON message.

Python interpretor is not liking it:

> NameError: global name 'null' is not defined

Function below:

```
def api_notification_invoke(notid):
data =      {
              "status": null,
              "message": null,
              "errors": null,
              "method": "POST"
                }

        js = json.dumps(data, indent=4)

        resp = Response(js, status=200, mimetype='application/json')
        return resp
```

Comment: Aren't you confusing null with None?

Answer (score 6):

Change all nulls to `None`. In Python the 'null' object is the singleton None